Why alcohol production as Jesus’s first miracle when alcohol harms so profoundly?
I am an adoptive mother.  Years after adopting two children I have learned that 80% of children NOT living with a biological parent was exposed prenatal to alcohol.  4-5% of the entire population of the developed world is so impaired by prenatal alcohol exposure that if the resources existed to actually diagnose everyone, they would have a diagnosis of Fetal Alcohol Spectrum Disorder.  This disorder impairs the typical development of the brain and body.
My child has FASD as well as 4 other diagnoses that are as a direct result of the fewer and less connected neurons and reduced speed of conduction.  My child has impaired coordination, initiation, language skills and has an intellectual disability.  It is expected that my child will not be able to care for themselves and will likely live in a group home unless supports fail and is homeless because no one understands the disabilities and helps when I am no longer around.
The alcohol consumed during pregnancy was done responsibly… one to two beer a couple times a week.  This would not be considered overindulgence.  There is NO safe amount of alcohol use during pregnancy.
As I have grieved this diagnosis I have reflected on how I have contributed, if any, to the social acceptance of alcohol consumption.  My contribution is very little.  My experience is that alcohol smells bad, tastes worse, burns going down and alters who you are and what you do.
I cannot think of another individual who has done more to promote the production, and consumption of alcohol than Jesus: the first miracle involves turning water into wine, and it is a critical element in some churches' communion.   It has become more than difficult for me to praise him after this life experience.
If the purpose of the wine is to provide joy and gladness then it’s unlikely that it was just fresh unfermented juice.  While wine and juice may not have been linguistically distinguished until more recently, I don’t think it’s plausible that when speaking of wine this was always fresh unfermented juice because there is a harvest time and a single time of year to make wine.  It would be impossible to source just juice year round for something like communion.  Wine would have almost always been actual wine with alcohol.
So with the discussion about wine not really being wine out of the way, can anyone help me view this from another angle?  And if you haven’t guessed, I really don’t relate to the idea of alcohol actually gladdening effectively.  I am certainly not feeling the gladness watching my children struggle everyday with simple things.
Why would Jesus perpetuate the use of alcohol?  He either didn’t know, or he did know but did it anyway.  My faith has experienced significant rupture.  Sadly.  I wish it were not so.

First, most people can handle their alcohol fine and aren’t addicted to it. Second, alcohol serves a variety of purposes - like sanitization. Back when, people would mix wine and water to make it safe to drink. They didn’t have sanitization plants to clean the water before coming through a pipe in your home. They had communal wells in the ground and streams.
Those that have an addiction to alcohol or a medical condition (like being pregnant) that would make it dangerous to consume alcohol are responsible for seeing to it that they don’t partake.
That it can be abused doesnt make it bad

First, I am very sorry about your difficult situation.  "The alcohol consumed during pregnancy was done responsibly… one to two beer a couple times a week."  My Church has a very active recovery ministry and my experience is that lots and lots of people lie about their alcohol consumption.

Fetal Alcohol Spectrum Disorder : If you drink in early pregnancy, you may harm your baby. But the risk of severe damage is small if you stop promptly on learning you're pregnant.. NIAAA.NIH.GOV.

It needs to be borne in mind that in olden times (and even today) many peoples did/do not have the luxury of treated water and drinking wine is far, far safer (due to the alcohol content) than drinking water which may have a high probability of contamination with some very severe diseases indeed. The wine we speak of is not the modern vintages of 12-13% alcohol. 'Wine' was much, much less potent. The term 'strong drink' is that which would be applied to what is sold commonly today.

Alcohol is harmful in the same sense that fire is harmful. Or food. Or even water. Many things are harmful, but they don't cause harm unless someone abuses them. Should kitchen knives be banned because they are harmful?

In addition to the other responses, wine at the time was generally drunk highly diluted (sometimes as much as 10 parts water to 1 part wine), and since this family was short on wine, I guarantee they diluted as much as they possibly could. Was there alcohol in the wine Jesus made - probably so, but He isn't giving hard alcohol to people already intoxicated.

We could also go the other way... instead of justifying the action of Jesus. Let's assume Christ was correct and not sinful, and then we must reflect on our own perspective. I am sorry for your situation... but at the same time Wine is a part of a sacrament as well. I do not believe Christ was encouraging abuse of a substance.

I actually don't think Jesus' wine was alcoholic.  The word "wine" used to be more generic and could sometimes refer to grape juice.  Because alcohol is created by leaven (yeast), and leaven is almost always a negative type in the Bible, I think Jesus would have made "pure" wine (unfermented). I.e., the Lord's supper ought to have unleavened bread and unleavened wine, as I see it. That opens up a whole discussion though.

First off, I'm sorry to hear about your child's disorder, that appears to have a knock-on effect on your child's but possibly also your own life long-term.
As a father myself, being lucky to have 2 healthy children, I can only imagine the pain and grief you have to go through. We love our children so much, and any harm that they have to face, touches our hearts deeply - if we could, we would protect them from all the pain, emotionally or physically.
I firmly believe that the same is true with God. When God created humans, I don't think his plan was for humanity to suffer (which is what many Christians believe).
When God made a promise to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, taking on their offspring as a special property of His, he gave those Israelites laws, and supporting instructions. That's why the Jews also referred to the Tanakh as "the law" or "the prophets".
According to the Bible, it is not a sin to drink alcohol in moderation. The Bible describes wine as a gift from God that can make life more enjoyable. (Psalm 104:14, 15; Ecclesiastes 3:​13; 9:7) The Bible also acknowledges the medicinal value of wine. - 1 Timothy 5:​23.
As with many of God's creation that Humans use, what matters is not necessarily if one is using it, but how it is used.
Jesus drank wine during his time on earth. (Matthew 26:29; Luke 7:​34)
In the well-known miracle which you mentioned, Jesus turned water into wine as a generous gift at a marriage feast. (John 2:​1-​10)
Jesus' intend with this miracle was certainly not to make anyone of the marriage guests sick.
According to recent medical studies, red wine has some health benefits when consumed in moderation:

Red wine may lower the risk of heart disease, stroke and early death.
Small amounts of red wine are linked to more health benefits than any
other alcoholic beverage. These benefits occur when a part of a
healthy diet like the Mediterranean diet (Healthline -Red Wine: Good or Bad?)

Note that in Jesus' days there was no Food/Nutrition industry which provided food supplements. Also, the quality of the wine that Jesus created, was certainly sublime.
On top of that, the quality of the food that people ate in Jesus' day was certainly much better, than the quality provided today - there was no micro-plastic in fish, nor were there pesticides sprayed nor genetically altered seed used. Many of modern day illnesses stem from the fact that in order to easily feed the planet, and to ensure income streams, things are being used that may improve yield, but that make the consumer sick. All of this are contributing factors to many of our health problems today.
You just cannot compare the Western diet (if that is where you're coming from) with the first century Mediterranean Diet. Nor can you compare the amount of food at people's disposal today with the food and drink that was available in Jesus' day to the average person.
Jesus making wine out of water was also a gift of mercy - the original wine ran out, and it would have been an utter disgrace for the newly wed couple to run out of wine on their most beautiful day. If you read the account carefully, you'll see that the couple did most probably not even notice this, and Jesus prevented their day from getting partially ruined - they just suddenly noticed that the quality of wine improved. They were not faced with the risk of the wine running out, so they could continue enjoying their wedding without tension. During the feast, they probably didn't even notice that it was Jesus who saved their party.
This is just to show you that there were no ill intentions by Jesus whatsoever in turning water into wine. He also didn't put his Jewish brothers in danger, as all the Jews were certainly well aware that you should not overdrink on such occasions. They knew the Law quite well.
Red Wine, by the first century standards, was even considered to have medical benefits - we don't know how the grapes were at that time, they may well have had more of the healthy substances than they have today.
While I can't give you any medical advice about your child - was alcohol really the only possible culprit for his/her condition? Could there have been other circumstances that may have contributed (of course without any ill intend)?

I have no idea about this topic, but what was "wine" like in that historical era? Was it mostly sweet and only slightly alcoholic, unlike wine today? Someone explained his pet theory to me once, but if anyone has a more evidence-backed answer, I would like to know. I've always taken this verse as an implicit statement that Jesus doesn't mind people drinking alcoholic beverages, but unfortunately, my dad sometimes drinks too much.

In the Old Testament, God describes the Promised Land as “a land flowing with milk and honey” (Exodus 3:8; Numbers 14:8; Deuteronomy 31:20; Ezekiel 20:15). This poetic description of Israel’s land emphasizes the fertility of the soil and bounty that awaited God’s chosen people. The reference to “milk” suggests that many livestock could find pasture there; the mention of “honey” suggests the vast farmland available—the bees had plenty of plants to draw nectar from.  So, the production and consumption of wine in the form of an alcoholic beverage was not a part of God's  plan for Israel who had  been drinking plain water in the desert to quench thirst.
But then, in the days of plenty, many yields of harvest like grapes and figs would go waste unless they were turned into something with more shelf life. Fermentation was one such activity. Wine clearly lasted much longer that fresh grape juice would. Slowly, people realised that wine in big doses produced 'kick ' which for some was more attractive than the taste of fresh fruit juice. But then, grape wine also had some good qualities if taken in moderation. It helped in digestion, as can be seen from St Paul recommending its moderate consumption to Timothy who had a problem with digestion( 1 Tim.5:23).
In Jesus' days the banquets were largely non-vegetarian , as can be seen from the phrase 'sat to meat' in some Versions of the Bible . Thus, a moderate amount of red wine served as a digestive agent. It was no fault of Jesus if the guests  shamelessly drank more than the measure originally served (That could be one reason why the Cana wedding ran out of wine, necessitating the miraculous intervention of  Jesus at the behest of the Blessed Mother).
As for the types of alcoholic products  we have today, they are made from different sources like malted barley and molasses containing less nutritive value vis-a-vis grapes. Most of the present-day evils of alcoholism originate in such products.

Noah planted a vineyard and got drunk in Genesis chapter 9.

Thanks, Mike Borden. But , Noah preceded Exodus. I wonder if Israelites were served wine in Egypt .

The two spies sent into the promised land went in at the time of the first ripe grapes and reported back with huge clusters of grapes.  Numbers 13:20-23.  I don't think the phrase "land flowing with milk and honey" precludes wine made from grapes any more than it precludes bread made from grain.

Thanks, Mike Borden. I have since edited my answer.

Note that "sat to meat" in the KJV doesn't actually mean "non-vegetarian". In English as used at the time, "meat" simply means "food", and "flesh" refers to "meat" in the modern sense.
